# Saving dataframe as dbf with simpledbf in Python?

Tags: python, attribute-joins, dbf, pandas

I am doing a number of joins outside of ArcGIS as pandas seems to outperform it. I read in the `dbf` file with `simpledbf`, convert it to a dataframe, then do the join:

```
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5

#Source of the join
data_source=pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\myfolder\\mysource.xlsx')

#Target of the join
dbf = Dbf5('C:\\Users\\myfolder\\mydbf.dbf')
d_b_f = dbf.to_dataframe()

#Join
d_b_f_2=pd.merge(d_b_f, data_source, on='COLUMN', how='left')
```

How can I save this dataframe as a `dbf` and overwrite the existing `dbf`?

I expected something along these lines to work:

```
final_dbf = Dbf5('C:\\Users\\myfolder\\finaldbf.dbf')
final_dbf = d_b_f_2.to_dbf()
```

but an error pops up saying that 'C:\Users\myfolder\finaldbf.dbf' does not exist. What do you suggest as a workaround? I wouldn't want to look into other packages, as I am sure there must be a way of doing this within `simpledbf` itself.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/51171998/820534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [simpledbf](https://github.com/rnelsonchem/simpledbf) cannot export dbf format as output (only CSV, SQL,pandas DataFrame,  HDF5 Table)
2) Pandas DataFrames don't have a `.to_dbf` method

Simply use [PySAL(dbf)](https://pysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/tutorials/fileio.html#dbf-files) and [DBF files and the pandas DataFrame](http://geodasandbox.github.io/darribas/2012/05/07/dbf-files-and-the-pandas-dataframe/) with the functions `df2dbf`(convert a pandas.DataFrame into a dbf), `dbf2df`(read a dbf file as a pandas.DataFrame) and `appendcol2dbf`(append a column and the associated data to a DBF) in [dataIO.py](https://github.com/GeoDaSandbox/sandbox/blob/master/pyGDsandbox/dataIO.py))  that you can adapt

```
import numpy as np
import pysal as ps
import pandas as pd
# adaptation of the function `df2dbf` to write your resulting dbf file
type2spec = {int: ('N', 20, 0),
             np.int64: ('N', 20, 0),
             float: ('N', 36, 15),
             np.float64: ('N', 36, 15),
             str: ('C', 14, 0),
             unicode: ('C', 14, 0)}
types = [type(d_b_f_2[i].iloc[0]) for i in d_b_f_2.columns]
specs = [type2spec[t] for t in types]
with ps.open("finaldbf.dbf", 'w') as db:
    db.header = list(df.columns)
    db.field_spec = specs
    for i, row in d_b_f_2.T.iteritems():
        db.write(row)
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but regardless if I try to overwrite the existing dbf or create a new one, I get the same error: `AttributeError: __enter__` pointing at the line `with ps.open()`. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: look at line 47 of  [dataIO.py](https://github.com/GeoDaSandbox/sandbox/blob/master/pyGDsandbox/dataIO.py) -> `db = ps.open(dbf_path, 'w')`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I also tried with 'w+' but got the same result. I don't get the meaning of that error message.

Comment: What is your version of pysal ?

Comment: My pysal version is 1.14.3

Comment: Then I don't understand why. I have no problem with the solution.